# How can I change/add a CNAME entry with PHP?

Tags: php, dns, cname, nameservers

Hello I am planning in renting a couple of servers for our next project, and I was wondering if any kind of provider is offering something like a nameserver API to be able to change or add CNAME entries, which we would need to create over PHP by someway...

Maybe somebody of you guys has an idea... :)

Comment: Maybe something like cPanel or Plesk, or (free) GNUpanel?

Comment: If you're willing to work with an external DNS provider, you should check out Amazon's Route 53: http://aws.amazon.com/route53/. It provides a very nice API.

Comment: If you have the DNS hosted on your server do what KyleWpppd said and use the cPanel or Plesk API. Most control panels will have an API. If its at your register try to find a register with an API.

Comment: I manage my dns with Route53 via PHP

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem in the make script, which would add/edit dns & reload it?
One more thing you need to do is to make sudo permissions for this particular script.